# Windwos phone 8.1 internet permissions

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

When I run app in debugging mode internet works normally, but when I publish it to the store internet doesn't work at all. So what is solution to the problem I'm facing? "Internet(Client & Server)" is checked in appmanifest file.

Comment: Did you check the "Internet (Client)" permission?

Comment: isn't the device with the battery saver mode activated?

Comment: Does the internet work if you build it in `release`, but not store published?

Comment: Thanks for comments but I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem. If you try to export app from account that you're not publishing from on windows store, then your permissions won't be included. **So solution is to export and publish from same account.**